# reactjs - useRef() with function component

Tags: reactjs

I want to `ref` my `child function component` in my `parent function component`, so that parent can call child method directly. it works well with class component, but somehow not working in function component.

this is what I have:

```
//child function component
import React from 'react';

function Testt(props, ref){
    return(
         <div>this is test</div>
    )
}

const ChildRef = React.forwardRef(Testt)

export default ChildRef

///parent function component
import React from 'react';
import ChildRef from './test'
import {useEffect} from 'react';


function App(props){
    const aref = React.useRef()
    function handleClick(e){
        console.log("item click")
        props.parent("hey")
    }
    
    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log(aref)//<-- this always {current:undefined}
    },[aref])

    return(
    <div>
        <ChildRef ref={aref}></ChildRef>
        <div onClick={handleClick}>click</div>
    </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

I always get `{current: undefined}`, not sure why.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You must pass the `ref` as the second argument to `React.forwardRef`

[See the docs here](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html)

Answer (score 0):

Seems you haven't passed `ref` to the `div` element of `Testt` component.

Try doing:

```
function Testt(props, ref){
    return(
         <div ref={ref}>this is test</div>
    )
}

const ChildRef = React.forwardRef(Testt,ref)

export default ChildRef
```

Also, to call child method from parent component use [useImperativeHandle().](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle)